# Calculate lat long Distance ORM query python django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

**Models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    web=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    lat =models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    lng =models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    # location = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False, srid=4326, verbose_name="Location")
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    avg_rating=models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    restaurant_type=models.ForeignKey(RestaurantType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    keywords=models.ManyToManyField(RestaurantKeyword,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Raw Query:

```
SELECT id,name,( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(" +lat +")) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians("+lng+") ) + sin ( radians("+lat+") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance  FROM newbackend_restaurant
```

In this code raw query is working fine but I'm looking for ORM query in Django.

Comment: You should explore geodjango https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: There are inbuilt feature to calculate geo calculations and also you can use geo specific queries. vote up if it was helpful